# How do I export an .APK file from phonegap if I don't have anything in the platforms folder?

Tags: android, cordova

I created a new project using the PhoneGap desktop version, it generated a lot of stuff, and I've been trying to export an `apk` file, but the problem is, there's no `apk` file in my project, and I don't even know how to export it.

P.S.: If you want my project tell me

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you added your platform? Do you have a platform folder? What's inside it?

Comment: @MegaAppBear There's nothing inside it, do I need to add something to it?, it's my first phonegap apk, I just followed the phonegap tutorial http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started

Comment: You need to create the platform(android,ios,etc..), build it, and then you will get the apk

Comment: @MegaAppBear how do I do it?, I mean, How do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to follow a Cordova tutorial. You can try this https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

That'd help you with android as well
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html

Comment: Thanks MegaAppBear, I'm gonna check em out. One question, Can I do it using android studio?

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but I think it's possible from what I've read in other topics.

Answer (score 0):

use this command in cli to export apk  `phonegap build android --debug --device`